# Abort pipe execution

Tags: angular, typescript

I use this code to control an autocomplete component.

In this code below, how can I abort ".find" execution based on some condition ?
For example, only execute if some "isOk" variable is "true".

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.control.valueChanges
    .pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
      tap(() => this.start()),
      switchMap(value =>
        this.modelService
          .find(this.searchUrl, this.searchField, value)
          .pipe(finalize(() => this.finalize()))
      )
    )
    .subscribe(values => this.loaded(values));
}

start() {
  .....
}

finalize() {
  .....
}

loaded(values) {
  .....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did to work:

```
this.control.valueChanges
  .filter(() => this.isOk)   // <==== used the filter function
  .pipe(
    debounceTime(300),
    tap(() => this.start()),
    switchMap(value =>
      this.modelService
        .find(this.searchUrl, this.searchField, value)
        .pipe(finalize(() => this.finalize()))
    )
  )
  .subscribe(values => this.loaded(values));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just pipe in the Rxjs `find` before your call:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.control.valueChanges
    .pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
      tap(() => this.start()),
      switchMap(value =>
        this.modelService
          .pipe(find(() => this.isOk)),  // <-- like this
          .find(this.searchUrl, this.searchField, value)
          .pipe(finalize(() => this.finalize()))
      )
    )
    .subscribe(values => this.loaded(values));
}
```